# Modifying empty string variable inside switch statement in function bash

Tags: bash, shell-script

So I have this function in bash that receives as first parameter an empty string variable and as second parameter a character,

```
function check_cases {
    case $2 in
        r) $1=$(echo "$1 Read");;
        w) $1=$(echo "$1 Write");;
        x) $1=$(echo "$1 Execution");;
    esac
}
```

I've tried all different ways to concatenate the string variable but it always says that

```
=: command not found
```

about the = operator. I create and empty local string variable inside a function like

```
local var=""
```

And pass it with a character variable

```
check_cases "$var" "$char"
```

I want to understand what's going on and how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to do a *pass by reference* type function.

These aren't really a good fit for for `bash` scripting.  We can *fake* it with the `eval` command, but this has a lot of risky behaviour (potential evaluation of commands embedded in strings) and so isn't recommend.

In *this* example, the code would look something like:

```
function check_cases {
    case $2 in
        r) eval $1=\"\$$1 Read\" ;;
        w) eval $1=\"\$$1 Write\" ;;
        x) eval $1=\"\$$1 Execution\" ;;
    esac
}

check_cases var r
check_cases var w
check_cases var x

echo $var
```

Instead it's normally better to use *pass by value* semantics; just return the value you want and have the caller append it to the variable.

e.g.

```
function check_cases {
    case $1 in
        r) echo " Read" ;;
        w) echo " Write" ;;
        x) echo " Execution" ;;
    esac
}

var="$var$(check_cases r)"
var="$var$(check_cases w)"
var="$var$(check_cases x)"

echo $var
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I realized that i was programming in bash using C or Java logic, your answer worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you want to achieve, but anyhow...

First of all, the syntax for value assignment is not

```
$val=value
```

but

```
val=value
```

Anyhow

```
1=value
```

won't work, because the variable name can't begin with a number.

To assign values to positional parameters, do this:

```
function check_cases {
    case $2 in
        r) append=' Read';;
        w) append=' Write';;
        x) append=' Execution';;
    esac
    set "$1""$append" "$2" # notice no space between "$1" and "$append"
    echo "$@" # print all parameters
    echo Number of parameters: $#
}
```